# Как расположить блоки в ряд следующим образом?

Tags: css, flexbox

Всем привет. Снова верстка. не подскажете наиболее оптимальное решение на флексах?
хочу первый и последний элемент расположить справа и слева прижатыми к краю,а средний ровно по центру

http://prntscr.com/mqdcsz

Сделал подобное,но там применил абсолюты в релативе и прижал каждый к краю

```
 clear: both;
    float: left;
    left: auto;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;"
```

может есть оптимальное решение на флексах?

Comment: Одна строчка: `justify-content: space-between;` https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: у меня он родительскому задан, я про дочерние элементы говорю.их хз как прижать влево и вправо

Comment: Они сами прижмутся